# How to match values from 2 different sheets in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare 2 different sheets with a macro, based on values.
I try to explain better.
For example i have 4 columns of datas like:

B6:B35 , C6:C57 , D6:D165 , F6:F234 in Sheet1

and a single column of datas like:

F6:F300 in Sheet2

i would like to see in red what data are missing from sheet1 that there are in sheet2 with a macro based on "cells that aren't empty", because datas are not costants in raws and columns , is this possible to do with VBA ?

For Example:

for each cell in the column B starting from B2

check if B2 exist in worksheet1 in columns B C D E F starting from row 6

then check if B3 exist in worksheet1 in columns B C D E F starting from row 6

exc... for every cell of worksheet2 column B with value

I try to give you a rappresentation of what i mean

Worksheet1 PRE-Macro

[image]

Worksheet2 PRE-Macro
[image]

WorkSheets POST-Macro

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/volDV.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ywd.png)

Comment: Why don't you post a screenshot that shows the colored cells and shows the empty cells issue?

Comment: i added two images  of an example  to the final result, i think i can do this task doing something like a match index function in VBA,  but i'm not sure how to do it and if it is what i need. That's why i'm asking here i thought someone could help me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Endwith some help, I figured it out and i made some changes about it, my final code now compare the 2 worksheets and highlight in red values that doesn't match, I share it, maybe one day someone will use it too

```
Sub Compara_fogli()

Dim IntervalloColore1 As Range
Dim IntervalloColore2 As Range
Dim Intervallo1 As Range
Dim Intervallo2 As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim c As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set Intervallo1 = Foglio1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set Intervallo2 = Foglio2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

With Intervallo2
    For Each cl In Intervallo1
        Set c = .Find(cl)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next cl
End With

With Intervallo1
    For Each cl In Intervallo2
        Set c = .Find(cl)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next cl
End With

With Intervallo1
    For Each IntervalloColore1 In Intervallo1
        Set IntervalloColore1 = .Find("", SearchFormat:=True)
        If Not IntervalloColore1 Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = IntervalloColore1.Address
             Do
                IntervalloColore1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Set IntervalloColore1 = .FindNext(IntervalloColore1)
            Loop While Not IntervalloColore1 Is Nothing
        End If
    Next IntervalloColore1
End With

   With Intervallo2
    For Each IntervalloColore2 In Intervallo1
        Set IntervalloColore2 = .Find("", SearchFormat:=True)
        If Not IntervalloColore2 Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = IntervalloColore2.Address
             Do
                IntervalloColore2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Set IntervalloColore2 = .FindNext(IntervalloColore2)
            Loop While Not IntervalloColore2 Is Nothing
        End If
    Next IntervalloColore2
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```